# enviar 2 variables get por ajax y como las recibirlas

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tengo el siguiente archivo donde hay dos `select`, año y mes. Quiero que muestre todos los datos donde la fecha sea del año y mes seleccionado, logró hacer la búsqueda con la variable del mes, me falta agregar en la sentencia el año pero no encuentro la forma. En el `div` con `id="estadisticas"` muestra el resultado del archivo `buscar.php`. Intente con la siguientes sentencia.

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE SUBSTR(fecha,1,7) = '?'
```

y

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(fecha,6,2)) AS mes FROM tabla WHERE date_format(fecha, '%Y') = '?'
```

el formato de la `? = '2018-11'` pero no me arroja datos.

Los archivos que utilizo son los siguientes.

Archivo `index.php`

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-4 align-self-center"> 
            <select class="custom-select pull-right" id="anos" name="anos"> 
            <option class="form-control texto" value="">Selecciona el año</option>
            <option class="form-control texto" value="2016">2016</option>
            <option class="form-control texto" value="2017">2017</option>
            <option class="form-control texto" value="2018">2018</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-4 align-self-center"> 
            <select class="custom-select pull-right" id="mes" name="mes">
            <option class="form-control texto" value="">Selecciona el mes</option>
            <option class="form-control texto" value="01">Enero</option>
            <option class="form-control texto" value="02">Febrero</option>
            <option class="form-control texto" value="03">Marzo</option>
            <option class="form-control texto" value="04">Abril</option>
            </select>
          </div>
         </div>
          <div id="estadisticas"></div>
```

Este es el `ajax`

```
  <script >
  $(function()
  {
  $('#mes').change(function()
  {
    var mes = $("#mes").val();
    $.get("buscar.php",{cargarFecha:mes})
    .done(function(data)
      { $('#estadisticas').html(data); });
  });
});
```

Archivo `buscar.php`

```
<?php
require_once('funciones.php');
        $obj = new funciones();
        $filas = $obj->atnXFecha();     

foreach ((array)$filas as $key)
    {
      $i= $key['estadoA'];
      switch ($i) {
        case 1: $cont_sr= $cont_sr +1;break;
        case 2: $cont_ep = $cont_ep +1;break;
        case 3: $cont_ob = $cont_ob +1;break;
        case 4: $cont_pr = $cont_pr +1;break;
        case 5: $cont_np = $cont_np +1;break;
      }  
    }
    $todas = $cont_sr + $cont_ep + $cont_ob + $cont_pr + $cont_np ;
   ?>
```

Archivo `funciones.php`

```
       <?php
              public function atnXFecha()
        {
            $this->v=array();
            try
            {
                $query = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE MONTH(fecha) = ?  ");

                if($query->execute(array($_GET['cargarFecha'])))
                {
                    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $this->v[]=$row;
                    }
                    return $this->v;
                    $this->dbh = null;
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex)
            {
                $ex->getMessage();
            }
        } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el substring no te saldrá ya que es fecha no varchar.
Tienes que usar `date_format()` con los parámetros ("%Y-%m").
Te dejo un enlace de referencia.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

---

**EDITO POR TU COMENTARIO**

para hacer un AJAX con las variables es:

```
                var parametros = {"nombre_variable": value, "nombre_variable2": value2};
                $.ajax({
                    data: parametros,
                    url: 'url_destino.php',
                    type: 'post', //TAMBIEN PUEDES SER GET, PUT etc...
                    success: function (response) {
                        //AQUI LLEGA LA RESPUESTA DEL SERVER
                    }, dataType: "json" //ESTO SI VAS A RECIBIR UN JSON POR PARTE DEL SERVER
                });
```

Comment: ya lo intente de la siguiente forma y no da resultados. 

"SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m') = '?' ");

También sin apostrofes

Comment: Si lo pruebas sin comodín (?) Te funciona?

Comment: asi "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m')", tampoco funciona

Comment: haciendo pruebas en mysql si funcionan por ejemplo esta SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE DATE_FORMAT(fecha, "%Y-%m") = '2018-11', así también SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE SUBSTR(fecha, 1, 7) = '2018-11' entonces creo que es la variable que se envía, pero no entiendo por que, la visualizo en una caja de texto y si se envía el año y mes

Comment: Preferible es que utilices tu consulta en tu código de muestra SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE MONTH(fecha) = ? and YEAR(fecha) =? y solo añades mas valores al array : array($_GET['month'], $GET['year']) , por que de las otras maneras que aplicas afectas el performance de tu sistema

Comment: y como los envío en la función ajax?

Comment: lo solucione convirtiendo el campo en la base de datos a varchar ya que era date, al momento de seleccionar el mes agregó el año, quedando el formato de la variable mes así '2018-11' y la consulta "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE SUBSTR(fecha, 1, 7)  = ? "

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar dicha tarea has lo siguiente en el código anexo comentarios explicando como funciona:

HTML

```
            <!-- quita las clases de "form-control" al "option" ya que no se pueden aplicar  -->
            <!-- renombre los id's para darle mas coherencia al código en Javascript -->
            <select class="form-control" id="selectYear">
                <option value="">Selecciona el año</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
            </select>           
            <select class="form-control" id="selectMonth">
                <option value="">Selecciona el mes</option>
                <option value="01">Ene</option>
                <option value="02">Feb</option>
                <option value="03">Mar</option>
            </select>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#selectMonth").change(function(){

            if($("#selectYear").val() == ""){
                //Puedes condicionar que seleccione un año antes de enviar
                //la información mediante ajax , esto permite obligar al usuario a seguir tu flujo
                alert("Antes de seleccionar un mes , selecciona un año por favor");
                $("#selectYear").focus(); //hacemos focus la select para que sepa de que elemento indicamos
                return false;

            } else {

                var month = $(this).val(); //Obtenemos el valor del "#selectMonth"
                var year = $("#selectYear").val(); //Obtenemos el valor de "#selectYear" aquí no aplica el "this"
                                                   //por que la función anonima no hace referencia a él durante el
                                                   //"change"
                $.get("buscar.php",{month:month,year:year}).done(function(data){
                    //{month:month,year:year} esto es un objeto y pues no estas restringido al número 
                    //de parametros que puedes enviar , procura tener coherencia con el nombre de las 
                    //variables y asi evitas perderte en el proceso de envio
                    $('#estadisticas').html(data); 

                });                     
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php 

    echo $_GET["month"];
    echo $_GET["year"];
    //Aquí solo cacho los parametros directamente solo para muestra de su funcionalidad
    //solo seria integrarlo en tu archivo que contiene las "funciones"

 ?>
```

Con respecto a tu consulta de las fechas , comprueba que el tipo de dato creado en tu tabla sea "DATE" o "DATETIME" para que la consulta pueda ser ejecutada correctamente. Ya que si es del tipo "VARCHAR" puedes usar "LIKE" en vez de "WHERE".

Comment: hago el ejemplo y te comento como salio, en cuanto al tipo de dato es "DATE".

Comment: @iselarojo si pudiste solucionar tu situación ?

Comment: muchas gracias! funciona excelente, pero como empleo las dos variables en el archivo funciones.php?